# I had two grubs but not anymore, and I want both back

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu Linux 20.04 and Kali 2021 installed, and before reinstalling both, I had two grubs, the main one showed up when I started the pc, it was the Ubuntu one, and the second one showing up when I selected the Kali option in the Ubuntu Linux's grub. The grub on which the pc started was the Ubuntu one, and if I chose to start Kali, it would start again and show me a Kali grub menu. How can I get both back to what they were ?
Thanks for your replies, but please, do not say "It is not possible", as I did have both of them fine and working.
Thanks

Comment: Could it have been one in the GPT/MBR, then second one installed as volume bootloader, at the start of a partition? In the OS installer you should see a select which lets you pick where to install grub in the partitioning setup phase. One will be something like `/dev/sda`, and a volume bootloader would be on something like `/dev/sda1`

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you say it was set up this way before, because normally Ubuntu just adds menu entries to boot the other distro's kernel directly rather than to load its menu.  You can manually edit your grub.cfg though and use the `source` command to load the other distribution's grub.cfg file.  That will then present the menu options as they appear there.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom menuentry to your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

  menuentry "Kali Linux custom configuration" {
    search --set=root --fs-uuid <UUID_HERE>
    configfile "($root)/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
  }
```

Then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

[6.4 Multi-boot manual config](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Multi_002dboot-manual-config.html)

E,g: let say your Kali root partition is `/dev/sda7`.

**UEFI boot**: the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0



menuentry "Kali Linux custom configuration" {

    search --set=root --label Kali --hint hd0,gpt7
    configfile "(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
  }
```

Then run:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
```

**Legacy boot**: the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

  menuentry "Kali Linux custom configuration" {

    search --set=root --label Kali --hint hd0,msdos7
    configfile "(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
  }
```

Then run:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: if I don't have a 40_custom, is it okay to create one ?
Or does it need some special formatting ?

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a newbie, but I copied it to a newly created 40_custom, then proceeded to update-grub, yet nothing happened neither changed. (I mean, I restarted my pc then chose Kali as the OS, but it opened Kali. Then I tried any other option related to Kali, to no avail.)
Did I do something wrong, or am I supposed to do something else ?
Thanks for putting time in this

Comment: i've seen it, very clear and precise, thanks a lot
In my case, Kali is /dev/sda7, so I have to remplace the /hd0/gpt9 by /hd0/sd7, is that right ?

Comment: @ChuckLennon Right `hd0,gpt7`

Comment: i've done all that you said, and everything is correct, but when I select the "Kali Linux custom configuration", it says "press a key to continue" then brings me back to the Ubuntu Linux grub
Did I miss something ?

Comment: @ChuckLennon switch to Kali Linux, check the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. If it doesn't exist create it through: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: It does exist, that is why I'm confused

Comment: @ChuckLennon What `sudo fdisk -l` show ? a `gpt` or `msdos` partition table?

Comment: It shows Disklabel type: gpt

Comment: @ChuckLennon I have tested the first example, It works for me.

Comment: Does the fact that I have a SSD whose directory is "/dev//dev/nvme0n1p" change the way I need to configure it ?

Comment: @ChuckLennon Use the first example by setting the UUID of partition where installed Kali. Or use `nvme0n1,nvme0n1p7` instead of `hd0,gpt7`

Comment: I mean, Kali is on /dev/sda7 so the SSD isn't involved in any part of the installation, but since it exists, does it affect any of the config files/boot order ?

Comment: Is this normal that when I use `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg` the output is just `menuentry "Kali Linux custom configuration" {` with nothing else ?

Comment: @ChuckLennon Your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is empty you need to create it through `grub-mkconfig`

Comment: Nono, I have others menuentries, from Windows 10 to `menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os`

Comment: but nothing on Kali Linux custom configuration's line